# How to get the build SDK version in windows phone 8 using c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, sdk, windows-phone-8, silverlight-4.0

Can I get the SDK version in windows phone 8 using c#.If it is possible give me a suggestion please. I have to display the build SDK version of my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the Platform / SDK version from WMAppManifest.xaml.

`<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">`